# Why do these MySQL queries give different results?

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_custum_advertisement WHERE 'group' = 1

SELECT * FROM `tbl_custum_advertisement` WHERE `group`=1
```

Comment: In Mysql you have to use ` instead of ' as column name delimiter

Answer (score 0):

You first query is comparing a literal `'group'` to a literal `1`.

Your second query is comparing the value of the field `group` to a literal `1`.

MySQL uses backticks to indicate fields, and single quotes to indicate strings (or double quotes, actually)

Answer (score 0):

Quotes (`'`) and backticks

```
`
```

are different.

`'blah'` is a literal string. But

```
`blah`
```

is a column (or other) name.

`'group' = 1` is never true. But a column named `group` might contain the value `1`, so

```
`group` = 1
```

could possibly be true.

Answer (score 0):

Backticks (`) are to be used as an identifier for tables and columns

Single quotes (') should be used for strings and string comparisons

Please refer to this question for further understanding

[When to use single quotes, double quotes, and backticks in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks)